# Append custom validators dynamically in angular form controls

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Let's imagine that i have an array of strings of validation enums:

```
const arrStringValidators = ['required', 'minLength', 'maxLength']
```

FYI -> arrStringValidators constant might be empty array, or might contain other values, etc...

And i have a object where i define all these validators:

```
const myCustomValidators = {
  'required': Validators.required,
  'minLength': Validators.min(10),
  'maxLength': Validators.min(1500),
}
```

Is it possible when i init the form first time, to assign validators dynamically like this:

```
...
this.fb.group({
 myValue: new FormControl('', arrStringValidators.map(v => myCustomValidators[v]))
})
...
```

BIG THANKS!

Comment: Yes It looks like it would work. You should change:’required': Validators.required, to required:Validators.required, in the object

Comment: yea that seems like it should work. what error are you getting ?

Comment: @ihorbond, it just says: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

Comment: @ihorbond if i remove: arrStringValidators.map(v => myCustomValidators[v]) from new FormControl() it doesn't show the errors and works fine